# Error type must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator when unpacking obj in an array

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript

Guys I receive a Typescript error when I use the spread syntax (...) to unpack an object in an array.
Here's an example:

```js
case Actions.CITY_CREATED:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        cities: [...state.cities, action.payload],
        currentCity: action.payload,
      };
```

currentCity has an interface below and also cities has an interface City[]:

```js
interface City {
  cityName: string;
  country: string;
  emoji?: string;
  date: string | Date;
  notes: string;
  position: Position;
  id?: number;
}
```

So how to unpack my object to an array correctly?

Comment: What result do you want exactly ? Objects and arrays are differents things, you cannot convert one to the other just using a spread operator

Comment: Off-topic, but I think you should normalize your `date: string | Date;`  property to only use a _single_ datatype.

Comment: What is `action.payload` in this context? Presumably it's an object conforming to the `City` interface? (If so, then `interface City` should be immutable: add `readonly` to all its property members) to avoid accidental mutation of data in your state-store - and `state.cities` should be `readonly City[]` - not `City[]`.

Comment: @FlorentM. I use spread operator to insert an array of objects with City interface and also I add to a newly created array new object which comes with action.payload. So in the end we have an array of old objects plus new one.

Comment: @Dai thanks for help, but currently I have a different problem

Comment: What is the error exactly ? Can you provide the values of `action.cities` and action.payload ?

Comment: @FlorentM. Type 'City[]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)

Comment: That is a weird case, can you provide a sandbox containing the exact same error ? Using codepen or codesandbox for example

Comment: Please [edit] to provide a [mre] we can paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing.